Spring Boot Kafka AdminClient not connecting to Kafka REST port, works with plaintext port
I am working on a Spring Boot project with Kafka. The AdminClient fails to connect when using the Kafka REST port, but it works fine when I use the plaintext port 40305.
Here’s my setup:
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PageEventRestController {

    private final StreamBridge streamBridge;

  
  @GetMapping("publish/{topic}/{name}")
    public PageEvent publish(@PathVariable String topic, @PathVariable String name) {
        PageEvent pageEvent = new PageEvent(name, Math.random() < 0.5 ? "user1" : "user2", new Date(), new Random().nextInt(9000));
        streamBridge.send(topic, pageEvent);
        return pageEvent;
    }
}

application.properties:
spring.application.name=spring-cloud-streams-kafka
server.port=8080
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=localhost:8082
spring.cloud.function.definition=PageEventConsumer

Error Log:
2024-10-07T16:37:55.440+01:00  INFO 18108 --- [spring-cloud-streams-kafka] [| 
adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient 
clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected.

pom.xml:
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-test-binder</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

Additional Context:

I start Kafka using the Confluent CLI with the command:
confluent local kafka start

The Confluent CLI reports the following ports:
| Kafka REST Port | 8082  |
| Plaintext Ports | 40305 |




The Kafka REST Proxy is not a valid endpoint for the Kafka Bootstrap servers.
The AdminClient must connect to a broker.
If you want to connect to the REST Proxy, use a Spring RestTemplate client.

I used spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers to specify Kafka's port, as the default is 9092, but with Confluent, it runs on port 8082. I believe the issue may be related to the new version of Kafka, where Zookeeper is no longer required.

No, the Kafka REST Proxy is a completely separate process/port from the broker. Confluent repackages Apache Kafka, and doesn't change it. I'm not exactly sure how you're getting port 40305, but if that's working, then that's correct... If you don't need the whole Confluent Platform, I suggest using the official apache/kafka Docker image
